# How to send email in order update?

Tags: php, email, magento

I'm using an intermediary payment, and created a method of reconciliation, to change the status of the request in magento, when I receive a notification of payment intermediary.

It really works, trading status in the database etc, my question is how I send email notification to the User who listens change in order status?

When you manually change the status of the application has the option checkbox to notify the client, I wanted the same thing only something like this:

```
When you finish updating the status in the database to send the email with the new status something like:
<?php
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
   $order->sendUpdateOrderEmail($newStatus);
?>
```

Comment: this works $order->sendNewOrderEmail()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply:

```
<?php
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
   $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment); // $notify is boolean
?>
```

Comment: add historic in admin -> $order->addStatusToHistory($status, $comment, $notify);